# Horizontal scrolling page using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to implement horizontal scrolling using flexbox. The goal is to make something like this, where the whole page scrolls horizontally and each list will also individually scroll vertically.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  /* flex-wrap: nowrap; */
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  height: 100vh;
  flex-basis: 460px;
  min-width: 460px;
  background-color: #F5F5EB;
}

.check-item {
  height: 100vh;
  flex-basis: 528px;
  min-width: 528px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: bisque;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: chartreuse;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: cyan;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: bisque;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: chartreuse;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: cyan;"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. As a suggestion, for cleaner code and greater efficiency, use the `flex` property instead of `flex-basis` and `min-width`.

With `flex` you can also disable `flex-shrink`, which would otherwise squeeze all items into the width of the container, preventing an overflow (i.e., no scrollbar).

I also added content to a child element to illustrate the vertical scroll function.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.menu {
  flex: 0 0 460px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  background-color: orange; /* switched for demo */
}

.check-item {
  flex: 0 0 528px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: aqua;"><span>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br></span></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: bisque;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: chartreuse;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: cyan;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: bisque;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: chartreuse;"></div>
  <div class="check-item" style="background-color: cyan;"></div>
</section>
```